# How to set the co-ordinate of baseline of edittext in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have my co-ordinates of baseline where I want to write my text in android. How to place my text on that baseline co-ordinates. I know how to setX() and setY() functions but they set the X and Y position of top left corner of edit text. I want to write on the baseline, if baseline of co-ordinates are present.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your co-ordinates to compensate for the top/left position.

```
 float adjustedY  = (float) y - myEditText.getMeasuredHeight();
 myEditText.setY(adjustedY);
```

Comment: my getMeasuedHeight returns 0

Comment: What is the height of your EditText in your layout XML? If it is a fixed height then you don't need to get the height of the view because you already know it. getMeasuredHeight() will not return a height until after the view is measured. Try moving that code into your activity's onResume method and you will see that.